# github issue tracker

Tags: github

Am I missing the point or is there no "resolved" status in github?

having status open/closed means there is no workflow to the bugs - this is a bit of a let down.

or is it there but i'm just not seeing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can emulate the states of an issue by using the labels. Label a issue as "resolved" should everybody inform, why the issue is closed.

You are right, when you say, that there is no workflow defined by github, but using the labels gives you the opportunity to work, like there is the workflow you want, even if this means, that you have to take care about the consistency yourself (e.g. closing a "blocked by other issue" with "resolved" feels wrong as long as the other one is open).

You can add as many labels as you want to an issue, for example "critical" and "bug". If there are dependencies, I suggest to add a link to the corresponding issues in the issue description.

Comment: Yes, or use a different bug tracker ;) I had a look at redmine, which looks quite nice.

Comment: heard on/off things about redmine. plus not sure how good the git integration is

Comment: Git integration in Redmine is great ... but it sucks for various other reasons (the main one being that the devs are so unresponsive to user contributions that it really doesn't deserve to be called an open source project).

Comment: FWIW, the "open source" in "open source" refers to the source being open =)  If they aren't responsive enough, just fork it (since the source is open) and be more response when others ask for support or integration.

Comment: @SirRobert Thats not entirely true. As you said "open" just means, that the source is open. That doesn't mean, that the license allows you to fork it and do whatever you want with it. Technicaly you can open source even commercial software (albeit thats unrealistic and stupid ;)) You should read the license first, or get in contact with the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we use in my projects:

**Workflow**:

1. Anyone can open an issue, and assign to the issue manager.
2. Issue manager will see coming issues in 'Assigned to you' list, and review the issue, assign to the right developer with or without comments; or have discussion with issue opener.
3. Developer should see coming issues in 'Assigned to you' list, and
   review the issue, commit the code, deploy the fix on testing site,
   and assign the issue to issue opener.
4. Issue opener should review the issue comments, verify the fix, and
   close it or reassign it to the developer for further fixing.

**Philosophy**:

1. Open issues are flowing, workflow is implemented by flowing to
   different people/roles.
2. Closed issued are dead, no code fixing or flowing should occur.
3. Issue opener will verify the fix and close the issue.